# Change file permissions with SFTP or SCP uing JSch

Tags: java, file-permissions, jsch

I have a user account, but on trying using this am getting exception for rssh. Is there any possibility to give permission of directory using other way other than `ChannelExec`. Based on the exception I come to know this account can't use `ChannelExec` to give permission of a directory or file. Thus is there any other way this account could give file permission without getting access to this user account for `rssh`. Please give you thoughts.

**Code :**

```
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
ChannelExec channelexe = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
channelexe.setCommand("chmod 777 -R " + depDir);                
channelexe.connect();

System.out.println("channelexe.getExitStatus:"+channelexe.getExitStatus());
```

**Output :**

```
channelexe.getExitStatus:-1:
This account is restricted by rssh.
Allowed commands: scp sftp

If you believe this is in error, please contact your system administrator.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to use the "exec" channel for this.

Use the [`ChannelSftp.chmod`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#chmod-int-java.lang.String-):

```
public void chmod(int permissions, String path)
```

---

Note that the method takes the permissions as an integer. So you cannot use `777`, as that's an octal representation of the permissions.

An equivalent decimal representation is `511` (= `7*8^2 + 7*8^1 + 7*8^0`).

See also [Decimal to Octal Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13147109/850848).

---

Though the `ChannelSftp.chmod` cannot set permissions recursively. The SFTP protocol does not support recursive operations of any kind.