# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send sftp request

Tags: jsch

WinSCP based same connection using account name, passphrase and private key for connection. But trying from code am getting this exception continuously.

Code:

```java
try
{
    session.connect();
    System.out.println("session is alive:" + session.isConnected());
    channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();

    channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    channelSftp.connect();
    channelSftp.chmod(777, depDir);

}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Manual Exception in updateDepositedFilePermission:" + CommonUtil.getExceptionString(e1));
}
```

Output:

```
session is alive:true
Manual Exception in updateDepositedFilePermission:com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send sftp request
        at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestSftp.request(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.sftp.CheckFTP.main(CheckFTP.java:730)

session is alive:true
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send sftp request
        at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestSftp.request(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(Unknown Source)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.app.sftp.CheckFTP.main(CheckFTP.java:730)
```

Comment: As per [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33822100/850848), do not use 777 for permissions, use 511.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's the main problem, but you are calling `Channel.connect()` twice.

First here:

```
channel.connect();
```

And again here:

```
channelSftp.connect();
```

Remove the second call.