# convert decimal to octal using a for loop

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my for loop. The for loop is supposed to convert decimal to octal. Can some one please point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dboh {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        int single;
        int val;

        //Binary
        String binaryString = "";
        int value = decimal;
        while (value != 0) {
        binaryString = value % 2 + binaryString;
        value = value / 2;
        }

       //Octal
        String octalString = "";
        for (decimal = val, single = val % 8, octalString = single + octalString, val = val / 8) {


        //Hexadecimal


        System.out.println("Decimal" + "\t" + "Binary" + "\t" + "Octal" +       "\t" + "Hexadecimal");
        System.out.println(decimal + "\t" + binaryString + "\t" + octalString);
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147109/decimal-to-octal-conversion) may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decimal Conversion error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142977/decimal-conversion-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your for loop like this

```
val = decimal
```

instead of

```
decimal = val



for(val = decimal; val > 0; val = val / 8){
octalString = val % 8 + octalString;
}
```

Comment: i get Syntax error, insert "; ; ) Statement" to complete ForStatement

Comment: Sorry bro. Now the updated syntax. Use this for loop

Comment: ok syntax is right but my octal is wrong 10 comes out to 2 it should be 12 any ideas thanks for the help

Comment: Goahead :) . All the best.